# React. How to unsubscribe event handlers in React componentWillUnmount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

How to solve these `warnings` from `ESLint` and make right `unsubscription` of `event handlers` below on `componentWillUnmount` in React 16x?

```
Line 137:  Expected an assignment or function call 
           and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
Line 138:  Expected an assignment or function call 
           and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

When try to unsubscribe from event listeners in React components:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.handleClick === null;
    this.handleSubmit === null;
};
```

Comment: You meant to write `this.handleClick = null`, and that will make ESLint happy, but it doesn't unsubscribe any event listeners.

Comment: Why do you think that it doesn't unsubscribe? @BenWest

Comment: You don't really need to unsubscribe from any event listeners that are declared directly on the jsx elements. You would just neew to unsubscribe if you added some event listeners on some globals like window or document...

Comment: No, we need to unsubsribe of every event listener on component unmout state. Espessialy when we use React_Router. See off docs @MartinReiche

Comment: @MaxWolfen because the reference to your function still exists, even if you change the value of `this.handleClick`. Micro-example: `var fn = () => {}; var subscriptions = [ fn ]; fn = null`. `subscriptions[ 0 ]` is still `fn`.

Comment: The link probably will be, but the handler will not invoke anyway, so this what I need, because these two handlers in the quesiton are fired by setInterval. So this th only solution to break them on Unmout. @BenWest

Answer (score 2):

The inline event is never added to the dom, it only lives in React world. So there's nothing to actually unsubscribe from.. you can ignore the eslint rule in eslintrc.json  by adding the following rule
`"no-unused-expressions": 0,`

Comment: No, you do not right, because on onmount event of React component I got en Error. That I create a memory leak when change Routing of component view

Comment: @Waweru Mwaura is absolutely right about that. Maybe you should read the docs, man... React uses a virtual DOM. You don't have tu unsubscribe from anything in the virtual DOM.

Comment: i am assuming that you are binding your methods, that is they are only executed when something happens, either a button is clicked or an action happens and therefore they are not executed until something happens. A component will unmount is used to unset variables that are initialized everytime a component is rendered and in this case, the two methods might not be.

Comment: @MaxWolfen: Yeah, nice troll.